# I Need Help: AJAX Request Error net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Many  users of my Chrome extension reported this error. Problem is that I can not solve it. One of the reasons is that it's working fine on my computer.

Here is the page that makes problem.

```
    // napravi glavni objekat - main
let main = {};
// napravi prazan niz u koji treba uneti valute
let coins = [];

chrome.storage.local.get('main', e => {
    if(e.main){
        main = e.main
        if(main.timestamp){
            let time_difference = Math.floor((new Date().getTime() - main.timestamp) / 1000);

            if(time_difference > 150){
                // pokreni glavnu funkciju prvi put
                check_convert_and_get_json();
            }
        }
    }
    else{
        // pokreni glavnu funkciju
        check_convert_and_get_json();
    }
});

// glavna petlja koja se poziva u odredjenom vremenskom intervalu
setInterval(() => {
    chrome.storage.local.get('main', e => {
        if(e.main) main = e.main;

        let time_difference = Math.floor((new Date().getTime() - main.timestamp) / 1000);
        if(time_difference >= 301){
            // pokreni glavnu funkciju
            check_convert_and_get_json();
        }
    });
}, 15000);

function check_convert_and_get_json(){
    // dohvati objekat convert
    chrome.storage.local.get('convert', (e) => {
        // ukoliko objekat konvert postoji, unesi ga u objekat main
        main['convert'] = e.convert ? e.convert : false;

        // u zvisnosti da li je korisnik podesio objekat convert, odredi URL za kripto-valute
        let coins_url = e.convert ? "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/" + "?convert=" + e.convert + '&limit=0' : 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?limit=0';

        // u zvisnosti da li je korisnik podesio objekat convert, odredi URL za celokupno trziste
        let market_url = e.convert ? "https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/global/" + "?convert=" + e.convert : 'https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/global/';

        // dohvati JSON
        get(coins_url, market_url);
    });
}

function get(coins_url, market_url){
    grab_data(coins_url)
        .then(data => {
            coins = [];
            // na osnovu dobijenog JSON objekta, izvuci potrebne podatke o valutama
            create_coins_object_inside_main_object(data);
        })
        .then(() => {
            // podesi trenutno vreme kako bi znali kada su rezultati poslednji put osvezeni
            let timestamp = new Date();

            // unesi timestam u objekat main
            main['timestamp'] = timestamp.getTime();

            grab_data(market_url)
                .then((data) => {
                    // na osnovu dobijenog JSON objekta, izvuci potrebne podatke o trzistu
                    create_market_cap_object_inside_main_object(data);
                })
                .then(() => {
                    // sacuvaj objekat main
                    chrome.storage.local.set({main}, function(){});
                })
                .catch(() => {
                    // sacuvaj objekat main
                    chrome.storage.local.set({main}, function(){});
                });
        });
}

function create_market_cap_object_inside_main_object(data){
    let market = JSON.parse(data);

    main['market_cap'] = {'total_market_cap_usd': market.total_market_cap_usd};
    if(main.convert) main['market_cap']['total_market_cap_' + main.convert.toLowerCase()] = market['total_market_cap_' + main.convert.toLowerCase()];
}

function create_coins_object_inside_main_object(data){
    JSON.parse(data)
        .filter(coin => {
            // prihvati samo one valute koje zadovoljavaju odredjene uslove
            return coin.id && coin.name && coin.symbol && coin.price_usd && coin.price_btc && coin.percent_change_24h;
        })
        .forEach(coin => {
            if(main.alerts){
                if(main.alerts[coin.name.toLowerCase()]){
                    if(main.alerts[coin.name.toLowerCase()].max < coin['price_' + main.alerts[coin.name.toLowerCase()].cur]){
                        chrome.notifications.create({
                            type: 'basic',
                            title: 'Green Alert',
                            message: 'Price of ' + coin.name + ' is above selected value.',
                            iconUrl: 'alert_up.png',
                            priority: 2,
                            requireInteraction: true
                          })
                    }
                    if(main.alerts[coin.name.toLowerCase()].min > coin['price_' + main.alerts[coin.name.toLowerCase()].cur]){
                        chrome.notifications.create({
                            type: 'basic',
                            title: 'Red Alert',
                            message: 'Price of ' + coin.name + ' is below selected value.',
                            iconUrl: 'alert_down.png',
                            priority: 2,
                            requireInteraction: true
                          })
                    }
                }
            }

            // na osnovu odredjenih parametara popuni coins niz
            populate_empty_object_and_push_it_to_coins_array(coin);
        });

    main['coins'] = coins;
}

function NotificationOptions(type, iconURL, title, message){
    this.type = type;
    this.iconURL = iconURL;
    this.title = title;
    this.message = message;
}

function populate_empty_object_and_push_it_to_coins_array(coin){
    // kreiraj prazan objekat koji zatim treba dodati na coins niz
    let empty = {};

    empty['id'] = coin.id;
    empty['name'] = coin.name;
    empty['symbol'] = coin.symbol;
    empty['price_usd'] = coin.price_usd;
    // proveri da li postoji konverzija u drugu valutu i obavi odgovarajucu radnju
    if(main.convert) empty['price_' + main.convert.toLowerCase()] = coin['price_' + main.convert.toLowerCase()];
    empty['price_btc'] = coin.price_btc;
    empty['percent_change_24h'] = coin.percent_change_24h;

    coins.push(empty);
}

function grab_data(url){
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
        var http = new XMLHttpRequest();

        http.onload = () => {
            if(http.readyState == 4 && http.status == 200){
                resolve(http.response);
            }
            else{
                reject(http.status);
            }
        }

        http.onerror = () => {
            reject(http.status);
        }

        http.open('get', url);
        http.send();
    });
}
```

I am trying to fix this, but I have no idea why it happening now and not before month or two...

Basically, I need to get JSON file and extract some informations from it. It shows error on first request which is https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?limit=0

[Here is the link to my extension in Chrome store.](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/cryptocurrency-price-trac/eoflfhfpgdhgbegbpgckkailbndcgpod)

Comment: the code seems valid and the JSON is received quite fine. Either your server (or Cloudflare CDN which you use) is misconfigured or your users have extensions that intercept HTTP requests and do some redirect loop. However the things you provided do not fail => most likely you won't receive help until you provide something more than this

Comment: Thank you for response. One user was able to fix issue by switching to Chrome Canary. What is interesting is that he got this error after 1 month of using extension. I push some update yesterday, but it was just cosmetic changes, so it should not be responsible for this. Code that I put here is a background page. You may think of it as a server and I didn't changed it for at least 3 weeks.